# Java AWT - Draw a Polygon connected by smooth curved lines

Tags: java, graphics, awt, computational-geometry

Here I am asking more silly graphics questions. Hopefully soon I will leave the world of graphics behind and plant myself firmly in the color-less middle-tier again. I have a newfound respect for people who are able to fiddle with images in pleasing ways through code.

That said, I am drawing a Polygon on a canvas. It can have an arbitrary number of points, but let's assume 12 for now. The polygon, as implemented, is connected via straight lines from point to point. I would like to apply some type of transformation so that the shape is drawn more 'naturally', as if someone had connected the points with a pen/pencil.

I'm not sure if this is too vague of a description. I think what I'm looking for is a bezier curve, but I'm a graphics (and geometry) slack-jaw. I'm interested in novel solutions in general, just something that makes a straight-sided polygon look more like a blob of ink. Maybe with controls to achieve a more or less 'natural' shape.

If you need any additional info, please don't hesitate to ask.

Kind thanks,
Matt

Comment: If AWT/Swing has built-in Bezier-curve-drawing (I have no idea whether it does or not), then you could do that. But my first thought would be to just "round the corners" which I think you could probably figure out on your own using the `Graphics` object. You'd just have a combination of straight lines and small arcs, connected together.

Comment: I don't think I can overstate my graphics incompetence. Right now I'm letting AWT do all of the work. :)

Comment: When I overstate *my* incompetence, I find that I must rely on particularly emphatic terminology, which is usually vulgar. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get started:
* create a [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html)
* add curves to the path using GeneralPath.curveTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
* get a [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object
* use Graphics2D.draw(Shape s) to draw the GeneralPath (which is a shape)

Optionally you can set the line cap and join style:
* Create a [BasicStroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html) (width=1, cap=CAP_ROUND , join=JOIN_ROUND )
* use Graphics2D.setStroke to set the stroke

The only hard part is that you have to figure out the x3,y3 of the method curveTo

Answer (score 1):

With a J2SE JVM you can cast any Graphics object to a Graphics2D object and then use this to draw Bezier lines.

[See here for an example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/BezierLab.htm)